# WordPress add_action, wp_footer and passing variables

Tags: wordpress, function, action, arguments

Scenario: need to add a function to wp_footer, need it to be an action so I can add_ / do_ / remove_ it, and it needs to receive variables.

Problem: `add_action('wp_footer', 'myfunc')` does not accept variables. `add_action()` instead takes priority and number of argument variables, so that you can utilize `do_action('myfunc', $arg1, $arg2...)` to execute `function myfunc($arg1, $arg2)`. But calling `do_action('wp_footer')` from a shortcode in the middle of your page is quite destructive!

Question: is there a better way to add actions, or is my approach just totally flawed and need revising?

Comment: I believe, wordpress.stackexchange.com is more appropriate for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Far better off to create a unique function that accepts your required variables, then add *that* as an action to wp_footer.